# Please help building a regular expression

Tags: regex

Well , i tried to develop one pattern but couldn't succeed building a regular expression that would check that the text doesn't match the following criteria

it should not start with anything like below

```
    http://
    http://www.
    http://
    http://www.
    www.
```

the general idea is that the user should not be allowed to choose his username which would seem like a url.

here are my attempts for different patterns i tried but these fail in one way or other.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function validate(name){

        var pattern = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
        var pattern = /^((http|https):\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([-.]{1}[a-z0-9]+).[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.)?$/;
        var pattern = ^([^www\.]([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$;

        var _test = pattern.test(name);
        alert("_test is " + _test);

        return false;
     }

</scipt>
```

Any help is deeply appreciated

Zubair

Comment: Regex in which language? Javascript?
Keep in mind that not all implementations of regex are the same

Comment: should 3rd and 4th examples be with https?

Comment: You can seperate this in 2 logical groups: the `http://` and the `www.` beginnings, of which both may not occur.

Comment: Timothy Groote, i require it in javascript

Answer (score 1):

It can be simplified in

```
://|www.
```

this example below is in C# :

```
//Pattern
string pattern = "://|www.";
//Execute the regex
Match match = Regex.Match(testInput, pattern);
//Test result 
if (match.Success)
   Console.WriteLine("It's an url!");
```

Comment: asfsdf:// will pass your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

this is your pattern `^((http(s)?://(www.)?)|(www.)).*`
you can test it [here](http://regexpal.com/).

```
function validate(name){
    var pattern = /^((http(s)?:\/\/(www.)?)|(www.)).*/;
    return pattern.test(name);
}
```

I've tried this works.

**EDIT:**

yes, I forget to escape dots too. Use `/^((http(s)?:\/\/(www\.)?)|(www\.)).*/`

Comment: shift66 it fails for this test data wwwdff.test.com